Setting a Single User Password on Ubuntu 20.04 EC2 Image
I have an AWS EC2 FIPS compliant 20.04 instance, I have applied the DISA STIGS to this instance, except for one.  Every time I set the password for Single User mode I am no longer able to boot the server.  Is this not possible on AWS?  I have discovered some new information, this is only an issue with systems that are in FIPS mode.  It seems like the prompt for the username and password comes up before TTYS0 is available for input.  If I grab a screenshot of the machine it shows the prompt for a username, but the EC2 serial console is not available.  For reference the instructions are below:
Discussion: To mitigate the risk of unauthorized access to sensitive information by entities that have been issued certificates by DoD-approved PKIs, all DoD systems (e.g., web servers and web portals) must be properly configured to incorporate access control methods that do not rely solely on the possession of a certificate for access.
Successful authentication must not automatically give an entity access to an asset or security boundary. Authorization procedures and controls must be implemented to ensure each authenticated entity also has a validated and current authorization. Authorization is the process of determining whether an entity, once authenticated, is permitted to access a specific asset. Information systems use access control policies and enforcement mechanisms to implement this requirement.
Access control policies include identity-based policies, role-based policies, and attribute-based policies. Access enforcement mechanisms include access control lists, access control matrices, and cryptography. These policies and mechanisms must be employed by the application to control access between users (or processes acting on behalf of users) and objects (e.g., devices, files, records, processes, programs, and domains) in the information system.
Check Text: Run the following command to verify the encrypted password is set:
$ sudo grep -i password /boot/grub/grub.cfg 

password_pbkdf2 root grub.pbkdf2.sha512.10000.MFU48934NJA87HF8NSD34493GDHF84NG 

If the root password entry does not begin with password_pbkdf2, this is a finding.
Fix Text: Configure the system to require a password for authentication upon booting into single-user and maintenance modes. 
 
Generate an encrypted (grub) password for root with the following command: 
 
$ grub-mkpasswd-pbkdf2 
Enter Password: 
Reenter Password: 
PBKDF2 hash of your password is grub.pbkdf2.sha512.10000.MFU48934NJD84NF8NSD39993JDHF84NG 

Using the hash from the output, modify the /etc/grub.d/40_custom file with the following command to add a boot password:
$ sudo sed -i '$i set superusers=\"root\"\npassword_pbkdf2 root <hash>' /etc/grub.d/40_custom 

where <hash> is the hash generated by grub-mkpasswd-pbkdf2 command.
Generate an updated "grub.conf" file with the new password by using the following command:
$ sudo update-grub

Unfortunately the issue is not solved.

Bumping this up to the top, hopefully someone can offer some advice.
